# Mock IEndpointRouteBuilder in .Net healthcheck

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I created a custom .Net healthcheck

```
public static class HealthCheckHighMark
{

    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapHighMarkChecks(
        this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {

        return endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/api/health/highmark", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new HighMarkResult
                    {
                        HighMark = HealthHandler.GetHighMark().High.ToString(),
                    }, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                    });
                context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            },

            Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("highmark")
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test to ensure that the response is formatted correctly. It currently looks like this:

```
readonly Mock<IEndpointRouteBuilder> _mockIEndpointRouteBuilder = new Mock<IEndpointRouteBuilder>();

[Fact]
public async Task TestHighMarkResponse()
{
    var _mockIHighMarkResult = Mock.Of<HighMarkResult>(m =>
        m.HighMark == "100");

    var response = HealthCheckHighMark.MapHighMarkChecks(_mockIEndpointRouteBuilder.Object);
}
```

My problem is that when I run the test I get this error:

> Message:
> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Stack Trace:
> HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHealthChecksCore(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String pattern, HealthCheckOptions options)
> HealthCheckEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapHealthChecks(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String pattern, HealthCheckOptions options)
> HealthCheckHighMark.MapHighMarkChecks(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) line 26
> HealthCheckTests.TestHighMarkResponse() line 108
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

The problem seems to be that `MapHigharkChecks` is returning `null`. How can I fix this so it returns `HighMarkResult`?

Comment: Its just a class with 3 methods that return values. In this case the `GetHighMark()` method returns the value of `HighMark`.

Comment: Any feedback on the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

> I'm trying to write a test to ensure that the response is formatted correctly

But the test is trying to invoke the health check configuration/setup

Move the `ResponseWriter` delegate into its own field

```
public static class HealthCheckHighMark {
    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapHighMarkChecks(
        this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) {
        return endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/api/health/highmark", new HealthCheckOptions {
            ResponseWriter = ResponseWriter, //<---
            Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("highmark")
        });
    }
    
    public static Func<HttpContext, HealthReport, Task> ResponseWriter = 
        async (context, report) => {
            var result = new HighMarkResult {
                HighMark = HealthHandler.GetHighark().High.ToString(),
            };
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None,settings);
            context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
        };
}
```

so that way it can be tested in isolation.

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestHighMarkResponse() {
    // Arrange
    HttpContext context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var report = Mock.Of<HealthReport>();
    
    Stream body = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = body;
    
    // Act - testing the code that actually does the work
    await HealthCheckHighMark.ResponseWriter(context, report);
    
    //Assert
    //... read JSON from stream 
    body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var reader = new StreamReader(body);
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

    //... and assert desired behavior
}
```